# Unexpected SyntaxError when naming a variable Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, syntax-error

I get an `invalid syntax` on what I thought would be a simple variable name (`snow_cone_volume`).

I have accounted for `pi` by `from math import *`. I'm not sure what's going on here, especially since this block of code has worked in the past.

```py
File "<ipython-input-113-8c607fe8ef65>", line 63
    snow_cone_volume = (1/3)*pi*(r_snow**2)*(n_height_snow)
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: print r_snow and n_height_snow

Comment: The problem is probably on the previous line, like you forgot a close parenthesis.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that variable name.

Comment: No problems with ```r_snow``` or ```n_height_snow```

Comment: Thank you @Barmar. You nailed it. Problem with parenthesis in the previous line.